# Linked Lists - Efficient usage?

Tags: java, collections

So I've been giving a project for school and was just hoping for reassurance towards the decision making I do.

My java skills are extremely basic and need to improve drastically soon! I just seem to be getting nowhere atm :P

Anyway, back on topic.

My first task is to create an interface directory that can do the following

[image]

Keep in mind this is assessed work therefore please don't provide answers. I have enough time to complete this since I've started early!

My initial approach for going about this task is using a Linked List. I don't know what you guys think about that? I may be completely wrong but based on the topics we have covered in School. LinkedList definitely seems suitable. I can add, get and remove.

Cheers for reading guys!

Comment: To get the best use out of this site I would recommend that you make an attempt first. If you run into problems, we'll help with those specific problems. If you finish it, but you're still unsure, try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: As a note, it's considered bad manners to post text (assignments, error messages, output) in the form of an image; it can't be indexed for search, and it is much more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are along the right lines. The `java.util.Collections` package will contain most of what you need.

I would actually use an `ArrayList` rather than a `LinkedList` as it is faster for random access and sorting.

However note that it says you should be able to find people efficiently and look them up by name.

That suggests using something like a `TreeMap` structure, mapping name to a class containing information on each person. Store the names as "Surname, Forename" and they will be sorted correctly.

That will only allow lookups based on the complete and correct name though. If you want to search for partial names the map is less useful.

Comment: Thank you that was very useful considering we've covered ArrayList and TreeMaps so that does make sense! I will accept your answer in 4 minutes - thanks for your advice.

Comment: Actually, you can use different collections to fit different requirements. Think of `HashMap<Key, Entry>` as an index. For instance, as well as your "main" collection, you can have a separate "index" for requirement `3`. You just need to make sure that when you insert / update / remove an `Entry` from the "original" collection, all of the "indexes" are also correctly updated.